# Simultaneous Multivariate non linear regression in R

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

My dependent variable is a matrix of 2 columns say `(y1,y2)`. And I have 3 independent variables say `x1, x2` and `x3`. I would like to perform multivariate non linear regression on this in `R`. Any idea how to do it?
For example, the multivariate linear regression would be simply

```
 lm(cbind(y1,y2)~ x1+x2+x3, data).
```

But how to do it for non linear least square regression of may be support vector regression.

Comment: There are many forms of non-linear regression, making your question very broad. Googling for `r non-linear regression` get's you a lot of good hits. If after working through those you still have a specific question about a specific method, feel free to ask another question.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra ok.. let`s take the case of non linear least square regression i.e. nils function in R. How to do it for multivariate setting?

Comment: I meant nls() function in R

Comment: Try `nlsystemfit {systemfit}`

Comment: @Robert Thanks! I will check out the systemfit package.